# Como inserir MOD 1000000007 no código Python

Tags: python-3.x, script

Entendo que o MOD 10^9 +7 é utilizado quando valores decimais são extremamente grandes. E para simplificar é aplicado o: %10^9+7.
Entretanto, gostaria de compreender a faixa de valores em que é utilizado o MOD 10^9+7.

Comment: Já resolvi minhas dúvidas, como posso retirar essa pergunta?

Comment: Sim, tem um link "remover", abaixo das tags.